# Centering a holding page for all devices - CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to better my basic html and CSS understanding. Not a table in sight and a CSS sheet to define elements on the page. (This is a big step up for me!)

My new site at the moment is just a holding page until I can get the new one produced (probably with Wordpress or similar so that all band members can change content without the need for too much work)

The site is http://mixtapenation.co.uk/

I followed a few tutorials and sites to try to put the holding text and icons in the centre of the page whatever the device.

However on a mobile device it is closer (visually) to the left margin, but looks OK on a large resolution monitor.

My code is probably wrong and I expect there to be an easier way to do what I have done,

CSS:

```
.centered{
   /*
        height: 105px;
        width: 469px;
    */
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    margin-left:-300px;
    font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'Questrial', sans-serif,'Didact Gothic', sans-serif,'Muli', sans-serif,"Apple Gothic","AppleGothic","URW Gothic L","Avant Garde",Futura,sans-serif;
   }
```

HTML:

```
    <div style="text-align:center" class="centered"> 
        <span style="font-size:72px">Mix Tape Nation</span>
            <br />
        <span style="font-size:24px">Coming Soon</span>
            <br />
        <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/126088079@N07/" title="See my photos on Flickr!" target="_blank"><img src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/goodies/white-large-chiclet.png" width="44" height="44" alt="Flickr"></a>
        <a href="http://www.reverbnation.com/page_object/join_mailing_list/artist_4333576" target="_blank"><img alt="Mylinks_join_mailing_list" src="http://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802892/production_static/20140812090746/images/my_links_badges/mylinks_join_mailing_list.png?1407835385"/></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/LiveMTN" target="_blank"><img src="images/Twitter_logo_blue.gif" width="45" height="37" alt="Twitter"/></a>

        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/mixtapenationband" target="_blank"><img src="images/SoundCloud_LogoPack_Dec2013/digital/square/sc_square_42.png" width="42" height="42" alt="SoundCloud" /></a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The used method for centering can obviously only work if you have a fixed size element, specifically in this case 600x200 pixels to correspond to those margins. You're essentially lucky it kind-of-centers right now in any browser at all - in my browser the element is 567x182 but it depends fully on font rendering method now.

Answer (score 0):

Use that

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

for centering it in the middle (left, right)

Answer (score 0):

I guess want you are looking for is a responsive webpage, as there is no one simple solution that will work on all devices.

You could try this code:

**Style.css**

```
margin-top:20%;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'Questrial', sans-serif,'Didact Gothic', sans-serif,'Muli', sans-serif,"Apple Gothic","AppleGothic","URW Gothic L","Avant Garde",Futura,sans-serif;
```

remove other properties.

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=rJF4y8tUhf)

Answer (score 0):

This shoud be fine:

**CSS**

```
.centered{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', 'Questrial', sans-serif,'Didact Gothic', sans-serif,'Muli', sans-serif,"Apple Gothic","AppleGothic","URW Gothic L","Avant Garde",Futura,sans-serif;
}

.centered a img {
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="text-align:center" class="centered"> 
  <span style="font-size:72px">Mix Tape Nation</span>
  <br />
  <span style="font-size:24px">Coming Soon</span>
  <br />
  <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/126088079@N07/" title="See my photos on Flickr!" target="_blank"><img src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/goodies/white-large-chiclet.png" width="44" height="44" alt="Flickr"></a>
  <a href="http://www.reverbnation.com/page_object/join_mailing_list/artist_4333576" target="_blank"><img alt="Mylinks_join_mailing_list" src="http://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802892/production_static/20140812090746/images/my_links_badges/mylinks_join_mailing_list.png?1407835385"/></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/LiveMTN" target="_blank"><img src="images/Twitter_logo_blue.gif" width="45" height="37" alt="Twitter"/></a>

  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/mixtapenationband" target="_blank"><img src="images/SoundCloud_LogoPack_Dec2013/digital/square/sc_square_42.png" width="42" height="42" alt="SoundCloud" /></a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

centering  an absolute container

```
.container{
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top: -50px; /* half the size of the height */
    margin-left: -50px;   /* half the size of the width */
}
```